# Want to add suffix before file name extension with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have below code that adds listed suffix and prefix to file names listed in "B" column. But problem is, it adds suffix after file extension. I want to add text at the end of file names.
i.e if file name is test.txt and I want, 1test9.txt but code renames it as 1test.txt9

```
Sub Add_Pre_Suf()
Dim Pre, Suf As String
Dim r As Range
Pre = Range("C2").Value
Suf = Range("D2").Value
Range("B2").Select
'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
With Selection

    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Pre & r.Value & Suf
    Next

End With
RenameFiles
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job nicely:-

```
Sub Add_Pre_Suf()
        ' 21 Mar 2017

        Dim Pre As String, Suf As String
        Dim Splt() As String
        Dim Ext As String
        Dim R As Long, Rend As Long

        Pre = Range("C2").Value
        Suf = Range("D2").Value

        Rend = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 2 To Rend
            With Cells(R, 2)                     ' 2 = "B"
                If Len(.Value) Then
                    Splt = Split(.Value, ".")
                    Ext = Splt(UBound(Splt))
                    ReDim Preserve Splt(UBound(Splt) - 1)
                    .Value = Pre & " " & Trim(Join(Splt, ".")) & " " & Suf & "." & Ext
                End If
            End With
        Next R

        RenameFiles
    End Sub
```

Be a little careful about when you call this code because it doesn't specify the sheet, therefore working on the ActiveSheet. I wouldn't call the 'RenameFiles' procedure without first checking that the names are indeed what I expect them to be.

Note that `Range("C2")` might be referred to as `Cells(2, 3)`

Comment: If `.Value` doesn't contain a `.` this is a run-time error 9 (subscript out of range)

Comment: Yes, the error will occur on the Redim line. However, if there is content in cells(R, 2) at all it is likely to be a valid file name which has a period in it. If the file name isn't valid, an error will be welcome before the RenameFiles sub is called. To avid such an error make the Redim line subject to this condition: If Ubound(Splt) Then ... and place the End If below the .Value line (above the next End If). Comintern: You might also check if the file exists at that point but need to have the path for that.

Comment: Nice. working as expected. Just made small change to below line to skip from adding blank space: .Value = Pre & Trim(Join(Splt, ".")) & Suf & "." & Ext

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` for this.  Just add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime:

```
With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = r.Value
    r.Value = Pre & .GetBaseName(filePath) & Suf & "." & _
              .GetExtensionName(filePath)
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is that your Column B already has the file extension. You can split the file extension from the column and add the suffix before adding back the file extension. You can change your code to do something similar.

```
With Selection
    For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Pre & left(r.Value,find(".",r.Value)-1) & Suf & right (r.Value,len(r.Value)-find(".",r.Value)+1)
    Next
End With
```

Edit: A better code which will work for extensions which are of any number of characters.

Comment: `xlsx`? Not all file extensions are 3 characters long.

Comment: Thank you, I have modified the code to accommodate extensions with more than 3 characters.